# I'm trying to generate the parse tree for Antlr4 Python3.g4 grammar file, to parse python3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, antlr, antlr4, grammar

I'm using ANTLR4 and trying to generate a parse tree for a python file I have. I used the grammar file python3.g4 from the ANTLR4 documentation. I have the antlr4-python3-runtime installed, and I have ran this command:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python3 Python3.g4
```

This generated my parser and lexer files.

In Python3Lexer.py, I had errors for:

```
from typing.io import TextIO
```

so I changed it to:

```
from typing import TextIO
```

I also created this file called pythonparser.py, which is in the same folder as the parser and lexer files, to call onto the parser:

```
import sys
from antlr4 import *
from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
from Python3Parser import Python3Parser

def main(argv):
    input_stream = FileStream(argv[1])
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.single_input()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

I have also made a test.py file, which is in the same folder as the antlr grammars, with:

```
print("hello world")
```

I tried to run the grammar on this file to parse it, using the command:

```
python3 pythonparser.py test.py
```

Im not sure what to do as it doesn't work for me.

I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Fari/Developer/PRJ/project/antlr/pythonparser.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
  File "/Users/Fari/Developer/PRJ/project/antlr/Python3Lexer.py", line 19, in <module>
    LanguageParser = getattr(importlib.import_module('{}Parser'.format(module_path)), '{}Parser'.format(language_name))
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Fari/Developer/PRJ/project/antlr/Python3Parser.py", line 446, in <module>
    class Python3Parser ( Parser ):
  File "/Users/Fari/Developer/PRJ/project/antlr/Python3Parser.py", line 450, in Python3Parser
    atn = ATNDeserializer().deserialize(serializedATN())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 60, in deserialize
    self.reset(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 90, in reset
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    temp = [ adjust(c) for c in data ]
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/antlr4/atn/ATNDeserializer.py", line 88, in adjust
    v = ord(c)
        ^^^^^^
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of Python grammars. The ones you need are these:

- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3Lexer.g4
- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3Parser.g4

After you've downloaded both these grammars, you need to preprocess them by running the file [transformGrammar.py](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3/transformGrammar.py) in the same folder as where the 2 grammar files are in.

Now download these 2 classes into the same folder:

- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3/Python3LexerBase.py
- https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3/Python3/Python3ParserBase.py

When that is all done, generate the lexer and parser Python classes:

```bash
java -jar antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar *.g4 -Dlanguage=Python3
```

And if you now run the file:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
from Python3Parser import Python3Parser

def main():
    input_stream = InputStream('print("hello world")\n')
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.single_input()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the following output will be printed:

```
(single_input (simple_stmts (simple_stmt (expr_stmt (testlist_star_expr (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom (name print)) (trailer ( (arglist (argument (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom "hello world"))))))))))))))))) ))))))))))))))))))) \n))
```

Note that I did not change anything else (no `typing.io` to `typing` was needed). I used:

- Python 3.10.9
- ANTLR 4.11.1

### EDIT

When I stick the following in a file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3Lexer.g4
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3Parser.g4
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3/transformGrammar.py
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3/Python3LexerBase.py 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/python/python3/Python3/Python3ParserBase.py
wget https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar

python3 transformGrammar.py

pip install antlr4-python3-runtime

java -jar antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar *.g4 -Dlanguage=Python3

cat << EOF > main.py
from antlr4 import *
from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
from Python3Parser import Python3Parser

def main():
    input_stream = InputStream('print("hello world")\n')
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.single_input()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
EOF

python3 --version

python3 main.py
```

and run this file, I get the following output:

```
...

antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar              100%[============================================================================>]   3,38M  9,33MB/s    in 0,4s

2023-01-31 10:51:47 (9,33 MB/s) - ‘antlr-4.11.1-complete.jar’ saved [3547867/3547867]

Altering Python3Lexer.g4
Writing ...
Altering Python3Parser.g4
Writing ...
Requirement already satisfied: antlr4-python3-runtime in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (4.11.1)
Python 3.10.9
(single_input (simple_stmts (simple_stmt (expr_stmt (testlist_star_expr (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom (name print)) (trailer ( (arglist (argument (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom "hello world"))))))))))))))))) ))))))))))))))))))) \n))
```

Comment: Hi thank you for replying! I followed your steps but I still get the same error

Comment: @Fari, you're welcome. You must be doing something differently than me in that case. I edited my answer and added a bash script that runs fine on my machines (tested on Linux and MacOS).

Comment: I just tried out what you did, I made a file called test.sh and put in your code. but it still doesn't work for me. I am using MacOS. Any ideas why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Same one as in my post... I'm currently trying this again on a different laptop with some hope

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried it on another laptop and it worked perfectly! :D

Comment: Good to hear that @Fari

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied the Grammar from ANTLR's repository and it had a name set in the grammar's source code, like this:

```
parser grammar PythonParser;
```

This name must match the grammar's file name. So the file should be named `PythonParser.g4`.