# Parsing python files using ANTLR

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4

Using these steps [I'm trying to generate the parse tree for Antlr4 Python3.g4 grammar file, to parse python3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294250/im-trying-to-generate-the-parse-tree-for-antlr4-python3-g4-grammar-file-to-par), I've generated my python parser using ANTLR. But I'm unsure how to pass in a python file as the InputStream doesn't accept this.

I've currently managed to pass it in as a text file:

```
def main():
    with open('testingText.txt') as file:
        data = file.read()


    input_stream = InputStream(data)
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.single_input()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))
```

But I get errors to do with 'mismatched input <EOF>' and sometimes 'no viable alternative as input <EOF>'

I would like to pass in a .py file, and I'm not sure what to do about the <EOF> issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure, I'd need to know what `testingText.txt` contains, but I'm pretty sure that the parser expects a line break at the end of the file and `testingText.txt` does not contains a trailing line break.

You could try this:

```py
with open('testingText.txt') as file:
    data = f'{file.read()}\n'
```

#### EDIT

And if `testingText.txt` contains:

```py
class myClass:
    x=5
    print("hello world")
```

parse it like this:

```py
from antlr4 import *
from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
from Python3Parser import Python3Parser


def main():
    with open('testingText.txt') as file:
        data = f'{file.read()}\n'

    input_stream = InputStream(data)
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    tree = parser.file_input()
    print(tree.toStringTree(recog=parser))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

E.g. use `tree = parser.file_input()` and *not* `tree = parser.single_input()`.

Comment: hi when I do this, it now says 'missing NEWLINE at '<EOF>'

Comment: What does `testingText.txt` contain?

Comment: class myClass:
    x=5
    print("hello world")

Comment: but they have spaces and are each on new lines

Comment: That input is no `single_input` but a  `file_input`. So do `tree = parser.file_input()` instead.