# I want keep comments in my ANTLR parse tree for Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR for my Python parser but I realised that the parser doesn't recognise comments. Is there anyway to fix this because I needed to identify the comments in the parsed code?

I've used this method to generate my parser: [I'm trying to generate the parse tree for Antlr4 Python3.g4 grammar file, to parse python3 code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294250/im-trying-to-generate-the-parse-tree-for-antlr4-python3-g4-grammar-file-to-par)

This is an example of what the test code looks like:

```
class myClass:
    x=5
    print("hello world")
    #Comment
```

and the result of the Python parser:

```
(file_input (stmt (compound_stmt (classdef class (name myClass) : (block        (stmt (simple_stmts (simple_stmt (expr_stmt (testlist_star_expr (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom (name x))))))))))))))))) = (testlist_star_expr (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom 5))))))))))))))))))  )) (stmt (simple_stmts (simple_stmt (expr_stmt (testlist_star_expr (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom (name print)) (trailer ( (arglist (argument (test (or_test (and_test (not_test (comparison (expr (xor_expr (and_expr (shift_expr (arith_expr (term (factor (power (atom_expr (atom "hello world"))))))))))))))))) ))))))))))))))))))) \n)) \n)))) <EOF>)
```

As you can see, the #comment line of code is not in the parse tree but I would like it to be

Comment: FYI, what you are trying to generate is closer to a *concrete* syntax tree than an *abstract* syntax tree.

Comment: The abstract syntax tree is used to generate code, so comments are irrelevant. One use for a concrete syntax tree is to format code, so it needs to preserve things like actual whitespace and comments so they can be restored. So, what task you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: There isn't a way to integrate the comments in the parse tree without changing the grammar. What you can do is change `-> skip` to `-> channel(HIDDEN)`. Then, when you need the comment, look on the token stream of "off channel" content, noting that for every terminal node, there will be an index in the token stream for that terminal. Otherwise, if you don't modify to "channel(HIDDEN)", you will need to query the character stream for content. For my parser transformational system, Trash, I do actually add comments as special nodes to the parse tree.

Comment: @kaby76 thanks for the help, I don't really understand how the "off channel" things works but thank you anyways

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the lexer grammar you're using:

```
SKIP_
 : ( SPACES | COMMENT | LINE_JOINING ) -> skip
 ;

fragment COMMENT
 : '#' ~[\r\n\f]*
 ;
```

all comments are skipped during the tokenization phase. This means the parser will never "see" these `COMMENT` tokens. If you want to keep these `COMMENT` tokens, you will have to remove it from this `SKIP_` rule (and remove the `fragment` keyword):

```
SKIP_
 : ( SPACES | LINE_JOINING ) -> skip
 ;

COMMENT
 : '#' ~[\r\n\f]*
 ;
```

However, when you do that you need to adjust many (many!) parser rules to accept these extra `COMMENT` tokens. This will be quite a task to account for all cases where comments could occur.